# Error incompatible types Tstringlist and Tarray

Tags: delphi

I dont understand the error:

```
 function StrSplit(input: string): TArray<string>;
 var
 delimiterSet: array [0 .. 0] of char; 
 begin
 delimiterSet[0] := '&'; // some character
 result := input.Split(delimiterSet);
 end;
```

Used the above in this way:

```
 lst :=TstringList.Create; 
 lst := StrSplit (richedit1.Text);
```

Error is incompatible types Tstringlist and Tarray.

Comment: I suspect that they are trying assign the result of this function to a TStringList variable.

Comment: Actually that is the actual function which Im using like this:

     lst :=TstringList.Create;
     lst := StrSplit (richedit1.Text);

PS missed the comment above that is correct goes to string list :-)

Comment: Use `lst.AddStrings(StrSplit(re.Text));` instead.

Comment: I recommend that you edit the question to provide an MCVE.

Comment: It works. thank you. If not much complicated to explain ..what was the error ?

Comment: You can't assign an array of strings directly to a string list. Not the same type.

Answer (score 3):

According to your comments, the problem code is the calling code. You write:

```
lst := StrSplit(...);
```

where `lst` is a `TStringList`. And this does not compile for the reason that the compiler told you. An array is not assignable to a `TStringList`.

Instead use the `AddStrings` method:

```
lst.AddStrings(StrSplit(...));
```

And for what it is worth, the `StrSplit` function is not needed. You can write

```
lst.AddStrings(richedit1.Text.Split(['&']));
```

Comment: `DelimitedText` with delimiter '&' in the stringlist can work as well.

Comment: could lst.AddStrings(richedit1.Text.Split(['&'])); be used with multiple delimiters ?

Comment: Yes. Just add them to the open array constructor.

Comment: Awesome.....thanx gazillion..took me 3h .

Comment: FWIW this is all documented. Have you found the documentation yet?

Comment: that'w where I spent hours. But I had trouble understanding the error...BTW Im not a prof programmer.

Comment: So, do you still need help with this?